# Forcing figure to new page

Tags: floats, includegraphics, clearpage

can someone help me please to fix this problem. I tried newpage and clearpage but nothing works. How can I force only the example-image-c and example-image (which isn't even displaying at all) on a new page.

\begin{figure*}[p] \centering

```
\subfloat[Text]
{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\hspace{2mm}\subfloat[Text]

{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}\hspace{2mm}\subfloat[Text]

{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}}
\hspace{2mm}\subfloat[Text]

{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}}
\caption[Short-Text]{Long-text}
```

\end{figure*}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one float per page.  The key here is `\ContinuedFloat` (caption package).

Note, you could have done this using 4 separate `figure*`s.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[p]\centering
\subfloat[Text]
{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}

\vskip\dblfloatsep
\subfloat[Text]
{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure*}%
\begin{figure*}[p]\centering
\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[Text]
{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}}

\vskip\dblfloatsep
\subfloat[Text]
{\includegraphics[height=18cm, width=0.7\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}}
\caption[Short-Text]{Long-text}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I wanted.